# Get code coverage in truffle test smart contracts

Tags: testing, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, test-coverage

I am working on a blockchain project and have several smart contracts to be tested. For that, I use the Truffle test suite and write JavaScript tests.

**I want to know, is there any way to get the code coverage for smart contracts in the Truffle suite?**

I have tried using this package [solidity-coverage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solidity-coverage/v/0.7.18). I ran it with

```
truffle run coverage
```

But it gives me the following error when running on the Windows machine.

```
Error: truffle-plugin.json not found in the solidity-coverage plugin package!
```

Any solution for this error or an alternative way to get the coverage?

Comment: did u add it to `truflle.config.js`

Comment: @RoshinieJayasundara I currently have the same problem. Have you now figured out how to find out the code coverage in truffle?